# Form validated but still submitting without values?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

im using javascript validation to check for values within each form field before the form sends to the database but when i click submit the form still sends even without any values.
To test it i clicked on each of the fields to clear them and then tried submittin the button

**here is the form**

```
 <form method="post" action="send.php" id="theform" name="theform">
<input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" value="First Name" onFocus="this.value=''" class="yourinfo" ><br/>
<input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" value="Last Name" onFocus="this.value=''" class="yourinfo"><br/>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="Email Address" onFocus="this.value=''" class="yourinfo"><br/>
<div id="datepicker"></div>
<input type="hidden" name="date" id="date">
<input type="image" src="images/sbmit-button.png" name="submit" height="49" width="190" id="submit" value="submit" style="margin-top:10px; margin-left:-2px;" >
</form>
```

---

**heres the javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// Place ID's of all required fields here.
required = ["firstname", "lastname", "email"];
// If using an ID other than #email or #error then replace it here
email = $("#email");
errornotice = $("#error");
// The text to show up within a field when it is incorrect
emptyerror = "Please fill out this field.";
emailerror = "Please enter a valid e-mail.";

$("#theform").submit(function(){    
    //Validate required fields
    for (i=0;i<required.length;i++) {
        var input = $('#'+required[i]);
        if ((input.val() == "") || (input.val() == emptyerror)) {
            input.addClass("needsfilled");
            input.val(emptyerror);
            errornotice.fadeIn(750);
        } else {
            input.removeClass("needsfilled");
        }
    }
    // Validate the e-mail.
    if (!/^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/.test(email.val())) {
        email.addClass("needsfilled");
        email.val(emailerror);
    }

    //if any inputs on the page have the class 'needsfilled' the form will not submit
    if ($(":input").hasClass("needsfilled")) {
        return false;
    } else {
        errornotice.hide();
        return true;
    }
});

// Clears any fields in the form when the user clicks on them
$(":input").focus(function(){       
   if ($(this).hasClass("needsfilled") ) {
        $(this).val("");
        $(this).removeClass("needsfilled");
   }
});
 });
```

---

**im also linking to a jquery file:**

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
```

---

ive tested it on its own and it seems to work but something seems to be over riding it and skipping past the validation in this page

==================================================================================

i still not working... basicallly do u think it might have something to do with the jquery UI datepicker that im also using with the form??  ive not included that in the form validation as i only wanted to make sure the firstname, lastname and email was filled out

i have this included in my form page:

```
<script>
        $(function() {
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    altField: '#date'
});

$('#submit').click(function() {
    $('#output').html($('form').serialize());
});
});
</script>
```

would this be having an effect of it submitting even though there are no values in the fields?

something is definatley overriding the validation and submitting it

Comment: You could use a jQuery plugin to not reinvent the wheel :)

Comment: @Veritas - Actually, with that HTML, plain `$("#theform").validate();` validation using **[this plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation)** would submit the form after an email is entered and the two other fields are left unchanged. - see my answer

Answer (score 4):

[**It's working for me!**](http://jsfiddle.net/pajtai/5FmZX/) (but it's probably not working how you imagine it *should*)

Once you enter a valid email, the form is sent if you hit `submit`. Why? Because you have already filled in `firstname` and `lastname` for the user - with the strings `First Name` and `Last Name`**!**

So you shouldn't just check for empty or error string filled first and last names, but you should also trigger an error if the first name is `First Name` or the last name is `Last Name`.

```
// Check for empty value, the error string 
//     OR the default values of "First Name" and "Last Name"

if ((input.val() == "") || 
    (input.val() == emptyerror) || 
    (input.val() == "First Name") || 
    (input.val() == "Last Name")) {

    input.addClass("needsfilled");
```

[**Working example**](http://jsfiddle.net/pajtai/Dr2J6/)

(I assume you use server side validation as the final check, since people like me just love  [**NoScript**](http://noscript.net/). )

(Also you declare 5 global variables at the top of your code and one more global in your for loop (`i`)... don't forget `var`.. just like you used for `input`)

Answer (score 0):

What if I disabled JavaScript? You should (also) validate on the server side.

Also **refactor your code**! You can start with **extracting methods**.

Answer (score -1):

You need to cancel the submit event. It looks like you're trying to do this with a return false or a return true. However, with jQuery you'll need to do it a slightly different way.

First, you'll need to have an argument name for the JavaScript event. I typically use e.

```
$("#theform").submit(function(e){
```

Then you'll need to update the following code as follows:

```
//if any inputs on the page have the class 'needsfilled' the form will not submit
if ($(":input").hasClass("needsfilled")) {
    e.preventDefault();
} else {
    errornotice.hide();
}
```

The e.preventDefault() stops the event from being processed. In this case, that means the form will not be submitted.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/bind/ - `Returning false from a handler is equivalent to calling both .preventDefault() and .stopPropagation() on the event object.`

Comment: do i just need to add what u posted to the javascript file? and it will work?

Comment: ive just tried adding what you posted and its still submitting without any values